Enable autoselect for post owner / post revisions keyboard shortcut
The keyboard shortcut for going to a post's owner or revisions pages don't enable autoselect. I don't see why not. Save me an extra keypress (next post) when I've already navigated via URL to a specific post. Enable autoselect for it.
